# How can I improve SPDK performance on userspace DMA access?

Tags: linux-kernel, vfio

I am working on a userspace PCI driver which uses SPDK/VFIO APIs to do dma access.

Currently for each DMA allocation request I need to fill up structure `spdk_vfio_dma_map` then call system call `ioctl(fd, VFIO_IOMMU_MAP_DMA, &dma_map)` to map the DMA region through IOMMU. Then later call `ioctl(fd, VFIO_IOMMU_UNMAP_DMA, &dma_map)` to unmap the IOMMU mapping.

This is working fine so far and looks like it's what SPDK examples are using. However I am wondering if there is a way to pre-allocate all memory buffer in userspace then in each DMA allocation request just use the pre-allocated memory instead of doing `ioctl` call each time?

Any idea is well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if I get the issue but the whole idea (of DPDK and **SPDK**) is to allocate all the memory you are using on application start or driver probe.

If you are using memory that is under application control all the time then you don't need to do `VFIO_IOMMU_MAP_DMA` and `VFIO_IOMMU_UNMAP_DMA` every DMA transaction. If this is not the case you have two options:

1. Do the `VFIO_IOMMU_MAP_DMA` and `VFIO_IOMMU_UNMAP_DMA` for every IO
2. Copy the payload to the memory that is already registered in `VFIO_IOMMU_MAP_DMA`.

First option is better for **huge** memory blocks, while second is better for small IO chunks.